# ScrollPane which allows for wrapping around the screen

Tags: java, performance, javafx

I have a ScrollPane which allows for wrapping around the screen through some nice code. However, in order to achieve this I have had to use 5 ImageViews with each of them being the size of the screen. This causes the computer to run very slowly when panning around and loading. Is there a way to distribute the weight on the system or optimize the code so that it runs faster? I have a 1 year old computer that has a i7 processor so I know that this is not the issue and that it is the code. Anyways here is the code I have.

```
package gameaspects;

    import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
    import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
    import javafx.concurrent.Task;
    import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
    import javafx.geometry.Insets;
    import javafx.scene.Group;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
    import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
    import javafx.scene.image.Image;
    import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
    import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
    import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
    import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Popup;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class SourceCodeVersion8 extends Application{

final double SCALE_DELTA = 1.1;
public double SCALE_TOTAL = 1;
public static int game_speed = 5, day = 1, month = 1, year = -813, pause = 0;
public IntegerProperty dayProperty, monthProperty, yearProperty, pauseProperty, game_speedProperty;
public int dragDetected = 0;//0 is no drag detected

static GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
static SourceCodeVersion8 sourceObject = new SourceCodeVersion8();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(task).start();
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Popup exitPopupO = addExitPopup();
    AnchorPane mapAnchorO = addMapAnchor();
    Scene mapScene = new Scene(mapAnchorO);
    primaryStage.setScene(mapScene);
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
    primaryStage.show();

    mapScene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if(e.getCode()==KeyCode.ESCAPE)
        {
            exitPopupO.show(primaryStage);
        }
    });
}

//Creates an AnchorPane for the map
private AnchorPane addMapAnchor()
{
    AnchorPane mapAnchor = new AnchorPane();
    ScrollPane mapScrollO = addMapScroll();
    mapAnchor.getChildren().add(mapScrollO);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
    return mapAnchor;
}

//Creates an ImageView for the map
private ImageView addMapView()
{
    Image mapImage = new Image("WorldProvincialMap-v1.01.png");
    ImageView mapView = new ImageView(mapImage);
    //Sets the map to full screen.
    int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
    mapView.setFitHeight(height);
    mapView.setFitWidth(width);
    return mapView;
}

//Creates a gridPane to hold the ImageView
private GridPane addMapGrid()
{
    GridPane mapGrid = new GridPane();
    ImageView mapView1 = addMapView();
    ImageView mapView2 = addMapView();
    ImageView mapView3 = addMapView();
    ImageView mapView4 = addMapView();
    ImageView mapView5 = addMapView();
    mapGrid.add(mapView1,0,0);
    mapGrid.add(mapView2, 1, 0);
    mapGrid.add(mapView3, 2, 0);
    mapGrid.add(mapView4, 3, 0);
    mapGrid.add(mapView5, 4, 0);
    mapGrid.setManaged(false);
    return mapGrid;
}

//Creates a scrollPane for the map
private ScrollPane addMapScroll()
{           
    ScrollPane mapScroll = new ScrollPane();
    GridPane mapGridO = addMapGrid();
    mapScroll.setContent(new Group(mapGridO));
    mapScroll.setPannable(true);
    //Removes the ScrollBars
    mapScroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
    mapScroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
    //Sets to the center image
    mapScroll.setHvalue(0.5);
    //Adds functionality to scrolling
    mapScroll.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, e ->{
        //Consumes the event
        e.consume();
        if(e.getDeltaY() == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        double scaleFactor =
                  (e.getDeltaY() > 0)
                    ? SCALE_DELTA
                    : 1/SCALE_DELTA;
        //Ensures that you do not exceed the limits of the map
        if(scaleFactor * SCALE_TOTAL >= 1)
        {
            Bounds viewPort = mapScroll.getViewportBounds();
            Bounds contentSize = mapGridO.getBoundsInParent();

            double centerPosX = (contentSize.getWidth() - viewPort.getWidth()) * mapScroll.getHvalue() + viewPort.getWidth() / 2;
            double centerPosY = (contentSize.getHeight() - viewPort.getHeight()) * mapScroll.getVvalue() + viewPort.getHeight() / 2;

            mapGridO.setScaleX(mapGridO.getScaleX() * scaleFactor);
            mapGridO.setScaleY(mapGridO.getScaleY() * scaleFactor);
            SCALE_TOTAL *= scaleFactor;

            double newCenterX = centerPosX * scaleFactor;
            double newCenterY = centerPosY * scaleFactor;

            mapScroll.setHvalue((newCenterX - viewPort.getWidth()/2) / (contentSize.getWidth() * scaleFactor - viewPort.getWidth()));
            mapScroll.setVvalue((newCenterY - viewPort.getHeight()/2) / (contentSize.getHeight() * scaleFactor  -viewPort.getHeight()));
        }
    });
    mapScroll.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED, e -> {
        dragDetected = 1;
    });
    mapScroll.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, e -> {
        if(dragDetected == 1)
        {
            if(mapScroll.getHvalue() <= 0.3)
            {
                mapScroll.setHvalue(mapScroll.getHvalue() + 0.4);
            }
            else if(0.3 < mapScroll.getHvalue() && mapScroll.getHvalue() <= 0.5)
            {
                mapScroll.setHvalue(mapScroll.getHvalue() + 0.2);
            }
            else if(0.7 < mapScroll.getHvalue() && mapScroll.getHvalue() <= 0.9)
            {
                mapScroll.setHvalue(mapScroll.getHvalue() - 0.2);
            }
            else if(0.9 <= mapScroll.getHvalue())
            {
                mapScroll.setHvalue(mapScroll.getHvalue() - 0.4);
            }
        }
        dragDetected = 0;
    });
    return mapScroll;
}

private Popup addExitPopup(){
    Popup exitPopup = new Popup();
    //Exit Panel
    VBox exitBox = new VBox();
    exitBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    Button exitPaneExit = new Button();
    exitPaneExit.setText("Return");
    exitPaneExit.setMinSize(75.0, 30.0);
    exitPaneExit.setOnAction(e -> {
        exitPopup.hide();
    });
    Button exitButton = new Button();
    exitButton.setText("Exit");
    exitButton.setMinSize(75.0, 30.0);
    exitButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        System.exit(0);
    });
    exitBox.getChildren().addAll(exitPaneExit,exitButton);
    exitBox.setVisible(true);

    exitPopup.setAutoHide(true);
    exitPopup.getContent().add(exitBox);
    return exitPopup;
}

static Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() throws IOException {
    long initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Finds the current time and links it with a variable
    while(true)
    {
        if(pause==0)//Makes sure the game is not running while paused
        {
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime >= 500 &&game_speed == 5)//Lowest game speed 10 seconds per day
            {
                day++;//Hey its tomorrow!
                sourceObject.setDayProperty(day);
                initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();//Resets time
                if(day == 32)
                {
                    switch(month)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            sourceObject.setDayProperty(day);
                            sourceObject.setMonthProperty(month);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 5:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 7:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 8:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 10:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 12:
                            month = 1;
                            day = 1;
                            year++;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if(day == 31)
                {
                    switch(month)
                    {
                        case 4:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 6:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 9:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 11:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if(day == 29)
                {
                    switch(month)
                    {
                        case 2:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(month + " " + day + " " + year);
            }
        }
    }
        };
};

public final int getDayProperty()
{
    return dayProperty.get();
}

public final void setDayProperty(int day)
{
    this.dayProperty.set(day);
}

public final IntegerProperty dayInitialProperty()
{
    if(dayProperty == null)
    {
        dayProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
    }
    return dayProperty;
}

public final int getMonthProperty()
{
    return monthProperty.get();
}

public final void setMonthProperty(int month)
{
    this.monthProperty.set(month);
}

public final IntegerProperty monthInitialProperty()
{
    if(monthProperty == null)
    {
        monthProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
    }
    return monthProperty;
}
}
```

Comment: You load the same image resource more than once. All 5 instances are sitting in memory and being rendered to the screen. You have not provided the size of the image file

Comment: I just cannot express this in a more polite way: That task is awful. Reasons: a) while loop instead of `Timeline`/`ScheduledExecutorService` b) You're using `int` values to represent on off states and sometimes they are confusingly named; e.g. `gameSpeed`: You expect this to be the speed of updates??? No either it's `5` or you don't get any updates... c) Furthermore those variables are used for inter-thread-communications without being volatile. d) Trying to reinvent [the wheel.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

Comment: @cricket_007 The image file is 4.09 megabytes.

Comment: @fabian a) Wrote this code a very long time ago... b.1) Yes I should use boolean values for pause. b.2) Haven't fully implemented that code yet. When implemented it should not only determine the speed of updates, but be able to be changed through the interface. c) Never heard of volatile before you mentioned it d) Wouldn't that fail with the times I'm using? The program starts in 813 BCE(currently). Haven't worked with it before but reading the documentation it seems it would not work with such early dates.

Comment: @AdamRen The [minimum supported `LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#MIN) is -999999999-01-01, which should be enough...

Comment: As @cricket_007 hints, just load the image once and use the same image for all `ImageView`s.

Comment: @James_D I loaded it once and have used multiple image views or does calling the method for returning the image view multiple times create duplicate images? As for LocalDate "However, any application that makes use of historical dates, and requires them to be accurate will find the ISO-8601 approach unsuitable." That is what I meant by it not compatible with early dates.

Comment: For the image, you may reference something called the Flyweight pattern. As is it, you've loaded multiple images, although it's the same file

Comment: @AdamRen "I loaded it once": no. You call `new Image(...)` every time you call `addMapView()`: five times in all. So you load five copies of it. Just load it once, store a reference to it, and create five different `ImageView`s from the *same* `Image` instance.

Comment: @James_D Yeah that was a large part of the problem.